# Calculate the maximum value of $x^3y + y^3z + z^3x$ where $x + y + z = 4$ and $x, y, z \ge 0$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, rearrangement-inequality

> Given non-negatives $x, y, z$ such that $x + y + z = 4$. Calculate the maximum value of $$\large x^3y + y^3z + z^3x$$

As an assumption, the maximum value is $27$, occured when $(x, y, z) = (0, 1, 3)$.

I have a guess about a working-in-process prove. Let $y$ be the median of $x, y, z$.

$$\iff (zx - yz)(y^2 - z^2) \ge 0 \iff y^2zx - y^3z - z^3x + yz^3 \ge 0$$

$$\iff x^3y + y^3z + z^3x \le x^3y + y^2zx + yz^3 = y(x^3 + xyz + z^3)$$

And further down the line is what I haven't accomplished yet.

Comment: Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/q/489292/42969 for a similar question. I assume that the same methods work here as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now, use AM-GM:
$$y(x^3+xyz+z^3)\leq y(x+z)^3=27y\left(\frac{x+z}{3}\right)^3\leq27\left(\frac{y+3\cdot\frac{x+z}{3}}{4}\right)^4=27.$$

Comment: I tried to apply Lagrange multiplier for this problem but it didn't work. Do you know why?

Comment: @S.H.W If it does not work (I want to try), so I think it because the expression $\sum\limits_{cyc}x^3y$ is cyclic and not symmetric. Also, LM it's not so strong method. Sometimes it just does not help.

Comment: I agree. To me, it's somehow vague. Please after trying LM, notify me with your result.

Comment: @S.H.W I tried, but it did not turn out.

Comment: How does $x^3 + xyz + z^3 \le (x + z)^3$? I feel so stupid.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Can you explain why cyclic and symmetric is important for LM?

Comment: @Lê Thành Đạt $(x+z)^3=x^3+z^3+3xz(x+z)\geq x^3+z^3+xyz$ because or $x^2z\geq xyz$ or $xz^2\geq xyz$.

Comment: @S.H.W Sometimes LM does not help also for symmetric inequalities. Just for cyclic inequalities the situation is more harder. LM is one of methods and not so useful in the general. It's better to know this method, but we can not wait from this method solutions in any case.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Okay, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I like the following way.

Let $\{x,y,z\}=\{a,b,c\}$, where $a\geq b\geq c$.

Thus, by Rearrangement and AM-GM we obtain:
$$x^3y+y^3z+z^3x=x^2\cdot xy+y^2\cdot yz+z^2\cdot zx\leq a^2\cdot ab+b^2\cdot ac+c^2\cdot bc=$$
$$=b(a^3+c^3+abc)\leq b(a+c)^3=27\cdot b\left(\frac{a+c}{3}\right)^3\leq27\left(\frac{b+3\cdot\frac{a+c}{3}}{4}\right)^4=27.$$

Answer (score 1):

I will give you a hint for the generalized problem:

$$f(x,y,z) = x^my^n+y^mz^n+z^mx^n\leq\dfrac{m^mn^n}{(m+n)^{m+n}}$$
for non-negative reals satisfying $x+y+z = 1$ and $m\geq n\geq 0.$ The simplest proof starts out by assuming $z = \max\{x,y,z\}$ and shows:
$$f(x,y,z)\leq f(0,x+y,z) = f(0,1-z,z),$$
and the RHS can be dealt with by AM-GM. This is a direct generalization but the proofs in the link on the comment in your post apply as well. The equality would be attained at any cyclic permutation of :
$$\left(0,\frac{n}{m+n}, \frac{m}{m+n}\right)$$

For your problem, you need to normalize first.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $x\equiv \max\{x, y, z\}$, I found "$=$" when $x- 3y= z= 0$, let's prove the homogeneous inequality
$$27(\sum\limits_{cyc} x)^{4}- 256(\sum\limits_{cyc} x^{3}y)= z\left ( 148\left ( xz(x- z)+ y^{2}(x- y) \right )+ 108(yz^{2}+ x^{3})+ 324xy(x+ z)+ 27z^{3}+ 14x^{2}z+ 162y^{2}z+ 176xy^{2} \right )+ (x- 3y)^{2}(27x^{2}+ 14xy+ 3y^{2})\geqq 0$$

> Given $n$ non-negative numbers $x_{1}, x_{2}, etc, x_{n}$ so that $x_{1}+ x_{2}+ etc+ x_{n}= 1$ but $((n> 3)\,or\,(n= 3, mk\neq 1))$ and $m, k> 0$. Prove that
>   $$x_{1}^{m}x_{2}^{k}+ x_{2}^{m}x_{3}^{k}+ etc+ x_{n}^{m}x_{1}^{k}\leqq \frac{m^{m}k^{k}}{(m+ k)^{m+ k}}$$