# Find the maximum of the value $F=x^3y+y^3z+z^3x$

Tags: inequality, maxima-minima, symmetric-polynomials, discriminant, uvw

let $x,y,z$ be real number.if $x+y+z=3$,show that
$$x^3y+y^3z+z^3x\le \dfrac{9(63+5\sqrt{105})}{32}$$

and  the inequality $=$,then $x=?,y=?,z=?$

I can solve if add $x,y,z\ge 0$,also see:  [Calculate the maximum value of $x^3y + y^3z + z^3x$ where $x + y + z = 4$ and $x, y, z \ge 0$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3296434/calculate-the-maximum-value-of-x3y-y3z-z3x-where-x-y-z-4-and-x)

But for real $x,y,z$ I can't solve it

[image]

Comment: How are you solving it? Using calculus?

Comment: FYI, the maximum is $\dfrac{9(63+5\sqrt{105})}{32}$, and the optimal $x > y > z$ are the three real roots of the cubic ${u}^{3}-3\,{u}^{2}+ \left( -{\frac {9}{8}}-\frac38\,\sqrt {105} \right) u+
{\frac {63}{16}}+{\frac {51}{112}}\,\sqrt {105} = 0$.

Comment: @inequality But I solved your problem. See my post. Maybe you have some question? I am ready to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have
\begin{align*}
 &x^3y + y^3z + z^3 x\\
 =\,& \frac{(x + y + z)(x^3 + y^3 + z^3) - (x^4 + y^4 + z^4)}{2} - \frac{x + y + z}{2}(x - y)(y - z)(z - x)\\
 =\, & \frac{3(x^3 + y^3 + z^3) - (x^4 + y^4 + z^4)}{2} - \frac{3}{2}(x - y)(y - z)(z - x)\\
 \le\, & \frac{3(x^3 + y^3 + z^3) - (x^4 + y^4 + z^4)}{2} + \frac{3}{2}\sqrt{(x - y)^2(y - z)^2(z - x)^2}. \tag{1}
\end{align*}
It suffices to prove that
$$\frac{9(63+5\sqrt{105})}{32} - \frac{3(x^3 + y^3 + z^3) - (x^4 + y^4 + z^4)}{2}
\ge  \frac{3}{2}\sqrt{(x - y)^2(y - z)^2(z - x)^2}.$$
Note that
\begin{align*}
 &3(x^3 + y^3 + z^3) - (x^4 + y^4 + z^4)\\
  =\,&
 -\frac{1}{64}(8x^2 - 12x - 9)^2
 -\frac{1}{64}(8y^2 - 12y - 9)^2
 -\frac{1}{64}(8z^2 - 12z - 9)^2\\
 &\quad + \frac{27}{8}(x + y + z) + \frac{243}{64}\\
 \le\, & \frac{27}{8}\cdot 3 + \frac{243}{64}\\
 <\, & 2\cdot \frac{9(63+5\sqrt{105})}{32}.
\end{align*}
It suffices to prove that
\begin{align*}
 & \left[\frac{9(63+5\sqrt{105})}{32} - \frac{3(x^3 + y^3 + z^3) - (x^4 + y^4 + z^4)}{2}\right]^2\\
 \ge\, &  \frac{9}{4}(x - y)^2(y - z)^2(z - x)^2. \tag{2}
\end{align*}

Let $p = x + y + z = 3$, $q = xy + yz + zx$ and $r = xyz$.

Denote $Q = \frac{9(63+5\sqrt{105})}{32}$.
(2) is written as
$$\left(Q -  \frac92\,q + \frac32\,r + {q}^{2}\right)^2 \ge \frac{9}{4}(-4\,{q}^{3}+9\,{q}^{2}+54\,qr-27\,{r}^{2}-108\,r)$$
or
$$63\,{r}^{2} + 3\, \left(Q + {q}^{2} - 45\,q + 81 \right) r + {Q}^{2}+ \left( 2
\,{q}^{2}-9\,q \right) Q+{q}^{4} \ge 0 
$$
or
\begin{align*}
 &\frac{1}{28}\, \left( {q}^{2}+Q-45\,q+42\,r+81 \right) ^{2}
 + \,{\frac { 384}{117\,\sqrt {105}+721}}\left( 8\,q+9
 +3\,\sqrt {105} \right) ^{2}\\
 &\quad + {\frac {3 }{114688}}\, \left( 24\,q+13-9\,\sqrt {105} \right) ^{2}
 \left( 8\,q+9+3\,\sqrt {105} \right) ^{2} 
 \ge 0
\end{align*}
which is clearly true.

We are done.

---

*Remarks*:

Actually, $\frac{9(63+5\sqrt{105})}{32}$ is the maximum.

Let $x_0 > y_0 > z_0$ be the three real roots of the cubic
$${u}^{3}-3\,{u}^{2}+ \left( -{\frac {9}{8}}-\frac38\,\sqrt {105} \right) u+ {\frac {63}{16}}+{\frac {51}{112}}\,\sqrt {105} = 0.$$

Let $p_0 = x_0 + y_0 + z_0, q_0 = x_0y_0 + y_0z_0 + z_0x_0, r_0 = x_0y_0z_0$.
Then
$$p_0 = 3, ~ q_0 =  -{\frac {9}{8}}-\frac38\,\sqrt {105}, ~ r_0 = - {\frac {63}{16}} - {\frac {51}{112}}\,\sqrt {105}.$$

We have (see (1))
\begin{align*}
 &x_0^3y_0 + y_0^3z_0 + z_0^3 x_0\\
 =\, & \frac{3(x_0^3 + y_0^3 + z_0^3) - (x_0^4 + y_0^4 + z_0^4)}{2} + \frac{3}{2}\sqrt{(x_0 - y_0)^2(y_0 - z_0)^2(z_0 - x_0)^2}\\
 =\, & \frac{9}{2}q_0 - \frac{3}{2}r_0 - q_0^2
 + \frac{3}{2}\sqrt{-4\,q_0^{3} + 9\,q_0^{2} + 54\,q_0 r_0 - 27\, r_0^{2}-108\,r_0}\\
 =\, & \frac{9(63+5\sqrt{105})}{32}.
\end{align*}

Comment: But it's my solution exactly! You wrote it only in the $pqr$ notation and the quadratic polynomial of $r$ you wrote as sum of squares.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I want to say pqr and uvw solutions are similar. But I never read your uvw solutions in MSE and AoPS in these years. I am not interested in UVW although I know it is very powerful. I refer to pqr.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Actually, I never read uvw solutions of anybody in MSE and AoPS. Also, I solved the similar problems using pqr method.

Comment: But I read your solution. All right. :)

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Thank you. You are kind. I think your uvw solutions always solve problems.

Answer (score 2):

We can use the $uvw$'s technique here.

Indeed, let $\dfrac{9(63+5\sqrt{105})}{32}=k$, $x+y+z=3u$, $xy+xz+yz=3v^2$, where $v^2$ can be negative, and $xyz=w^3$.

Thus, we need to prove that:
$$ku^4\geq\sum_{cyc}x^3y$$ or
$$2ku^4-\sum_{cyc}(x^3y+x^3z)\geq\sum_{cyc}(x^3y-x^3z)$$ or
$$2ku^4-(27u^2v^2-18v^4-3uw^3)\geq3u(x-y)(x-z)(y-z).$$
We'll prove that $2ku^4-(27u^2v^2-18v^4-3uw^3)\geq0.$

Indeed, this inequality is a linear inequality of $w^3$, which by $uvw$ says that it's enough to prove this inequality for equality case of two variables.

Let $y=z=1$.

We need to prove that $$\frac{2k}{81}(x+2)^4-2x^3-2x-2\geq0$$ and since $2k>27$, it's enough to prove that
$$(x+2)^4\geq6(x^3+x+1)$$ or $$x^4+2x^3+24x^2+26x+10\geq0$$ or
$$x^2(x+1)^2+23x^2+26x+10\geq0,$$ which is obvious.

Id est, it's enough to prove that:
$$(2ku^4-(27u^2v^2-18v^4-3uw^3))^2\geq9u^2\prod_{cyc}(a-b)^2$$ or
$$(2ku^4-(27u^2v^2-18v^4-3uw^3))^2\geq243u^2(3u^2v^4-4v^6-4u^3w^3+6uv^2w^3-w^6),$$
which is a quadratic inequality of $w^3$.

Now, prove that $\Delta\leq0.$

Can you end it now?

Comment: Some typos in the first: $a, b, c$, $x, y, z$.

Comment: @River Li  Thank you. I fixed.

Comment: The technique to write a cyclic $f(a, b, c)\ge 0$ as $g(a,b,c) \ge h(a,b,c)(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)$ such as $2ku^4-(27u^2v^2-18v^4-3uw^3)\geq3u(x-y)(x-z)(y-z)$ is useful since $(x-y)^2(y-z)^2(z-x)^2$ is the discriminant of a cubic.

Comment: @River Li Yes, it solves very many problems.

Answer (score 1):

It is not surprizing that Mathematica does not produce explicit expressions for $(x,y,z)$.

Using it with the restriction $x>y>z$, it gives that $y$ and $z$ are respectively  the fourth and the first roots of the equation
$$56 t^6-336 t^5+378 t^4+819 t^3-2079 t^2+1512 t-351=0$$

Using  @River Li's comment, $(x,y,z)$ are the solutions of the cubic
$$u^3-3u^2-\frac{3}{8} \left(3+\sqrt{105}\right)u+\frac{3}{112} \left(147+17 \sqrt{105}\right)=0$$ and, using the trigonometric method, they are
$$x=1+\sqrt{\frac{11+\sqrt{105}}{2} } \cos \left(\frac{1}{3} \cos
   ^{-1}\left(-\frac{91+9 \sqrt{105}}{7 \sqrt{2}
   \left(11+\sqrt{105}\right)^{3/2}}\right)\right)=3.71382\cdots$$
$$y=1-\sqrt{\frac{11+\sqrt{105}}{2} } \sin \left(\frac{\pi
   }{6}-\frac{1}{3} \cos ^{-1}\left(-\frac{91+9 \sqrt{105}}{7 \sqrt{2}
   \left(11+\sqrt{105}\right)^{3/2}}\right)\right)=1.20642\cdots$$
$$z=1-\sqrt{\frac{11+\sqrt{105}}{2} } \sin \left(\frac{\pi
   }{6}+\frac{1}{3} \cos ^{-1}\left(-\frac{91+9 \sqrt{105}}{7 \sqrt{2}
   \left(11+\sqrt{105}\right)^{3/2}}\right)\right)=-1.92024\cdots$$

Trying to convert to radicals would be more than problematic.

**Edit**

After a series of mistakes, using @River Li's comments, the factorization of the sextic as the product of two cubic polynomials
$$(t^3 + b_2t^2 + b_1t + b_0)\,(t^3 + a_2t^2 + a_1t + a_0)$$gives
$$b_2=-3 \qquad \qquad b_1=-\frac{3}{8} \left(3-\sqrt{105}\right)\qquad \qquad b_0=\frac{3}{112} \left(147-17 \sqrt{105}\right)$$
$$a_2=-3 \qquad \qquad a_1=-\frac{3}{8} \left(3+\sqrt{105}\right)\qquad \qquad a_0=\frac{3}{112} \left(147+17 \sqrt{105}\right)$$

Comment: Yes, that sextic equation can be factorized to two cubics, but Maple, Wolfram can not do it.

Comment: @RiverLi. How did you make it ? I tried in vain. Your comment is great. Cheers :-)

Comment: Assume the form $(t^3 + b_2t^2 + b_1t + b_0)(t^3 + a_2t^2 + a_1t + a_0)$.

Comment: +1 for your trigonometric solutions.

Comment: @RiverLi. Guess what ? This is what I did. More than surely some mistakes !! Thanks & cheers :-)

Comment: Yes, you have 60 years professional experience in numerical simulation.

Comment: @RiverLi. I made it ! Thanks

Comment: Yes, you got it!  I used Maple resultant command to get them.

Comment: @RiverLi. May I confess that I cheated doing it by hand ? I used $a_2=b_2=-3$

Comment: Wow, by hand! Admire！

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution given with computer aid, here [sage](https://www.sagemath.org). (The OP also uses a computational approach.) The plan is as follows. We use the parametrization $x=1+a$, $y=1+b$, $z=1-a-b$ to get rid of the sum condition, the function $E$ (notation) to be maximized is now a polynomial function
of degree four defined for all $(a,b)\in\Bbb R^2$. It is explicitly:
$$
\begin{aligned}
E &= E_4+E_3+E_2+E_1+E_0\ ,\\[2mm]
E_4 &= -(\ a^{4} + 2 a^{3} b + 3 a^{2} b^{2} + 2 a b^{3} + b^{4}\ ) 
=-(\ a^2 + ab + b^2\ )^2\le 0\ ,\\
E_3 &= 3 (\ a^{3} + 2 a^{2} b -  a b^{2} -  b^{3}\ )\ ,\\
E_2 &= 3(\ a^2 + ab + 3b^2\ )\ ,\\
E_1 &= 0\ ,\\
E_0 &= 3\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
It is clear that $E/E_4$ converges to $-1$ for $(a,b)$ converging in norm to infinity, so the given function $E$ has an absolute maximum, that can be found by finding the critical points of $E$, i.e. solutions $(a_0, b_0)$ of the algebraic system with two equations
$$
\tag{$*$}
E'_a=E'_b=0\ ,
$$
plugging them in $E$ one by one, and taking the maximal value among them.
It is easy to solve this system using computing power. The values are explicit (exact) algebraic numbers, we know for instance the minimal polynomial over $\Bbb Q$ of $a_0$, $b_0$, and it turns out, it is the same minimal polynomial. We also know a numerical approximation for the possible values of the optimal point $(a_0,b_0)$, and this is enough to "put the hands" on the point. The engine also computes $E(a_0,b_0)$ for all critical points, for each such value we have again the minimal polynomial and the approximation, so we "know" the point. By chance, the optimal value $\max E=E(a_0,b_0)$ of $E$ in an optimal point is the solution of a polynomial of degree two, so this value can be easily written down. Not so simple is the explicit formula for the optimal point, we need to solve an equation of degree three, but this can also be done. This was the plan, let us realize it step by step.

To have a picture in this introductory part, here is a plot of $\max(E, 25)$ for the variable $(a,b)$ running in $[-4,4]^2$. (The bottom truncation with $25$ was needed, else there is a steep fall caused by the $E_4$ term in $E$.)

[image: math stackexchange 4222935]

$$
%sage: plot3d( lambda a, b: E(1+a, 1+b, 1-a-b), (-4, 4), (-4, 4), %plot_points=300 )
%Launched html viewer for Graphics3d Object
%sage: def E(x, y, z):
%....:     value = x^3*y + y^3*z + z^3*x
%....:     return value if value > 25 else 25.
%....: 
%sage: var('a,b');
%sage: def E(x, y, z):
%....:     value = x^3*y + y^3*z + z^3*x
%....:     return value if value > 25 else 25.
%....: 
%sage: 
$$

---

We start by passing from the expression $x^3y+y^3z+z^3x$, which should be maximized with the given constraint, to a polynomial expression $E$, obtained by using the mentioned parametrization in terms of $(a,b)\in\Bbb R^2$. Recall that $\sup E$ is not taken "at infinity", so $\sup E=\max E$ is a global maximum, which can be computed by considering all critical points of $E$, taking the values in these points, taking the maximum.

Solving $(*)$ is done below by associating the ideal generated by $E'_a, E'_b$ in $\Bbb Q[a,b]$, then asking for its "variety".
From the human perspective,
it is also interesting to compute the result of eliminating one variable, here $b$, then $a$, from the two equations $(*)$.
Time for the code:

```
R.<a, b> = PolynomialRing(QQ)
x, y, z = 1 + a, 1 + b, 1 - a -b

E = x^3*y + y^3*z + z^3*x
J = R.ideal([diff(E, a), diff(E, b)])
Ja = J.elimination_ideal(b)
Jb = J.elimination_ideal(a)

print(f'E is the polynomial:\n{E}\n')
print(f'The ideal J is:\n{J}\n')
print(f'Eliminating b we obtain the ideal:\n{Ja}\n')
print(f'Eliminating a we obtain the ideal:\n{Jb}\n')
```

And we obtain:

```
E is the polynomial:
-a^4 - 2*a^3*b - 3*a^2*b^2 - 2*a*b^3 - b^4
    + 3*a^3 + 6*a^2*b - 3*a*b^2 - 3*b^3
    + 3*a^2 + 3*a*b + 3*b^2
    + 3

The ideal J is:
Ideal (-4*a^3 - 6*a^2*b - 6*a*b^2 - 2*b^3 + 9*a^2 + 12*a*b - 3*b^2 + 6*a + 3*b, 
       -2*a^3 - 6*a^2*b - 6*a*b^2 - 4*b^3 + 6*a^2 - 6*a*b - 9*b^2 + 3*a + 6*b) 
    of Multivariate Polynomial Ring in a, b over Rational Field

Eliminating b we obtain the ideal:
Ideal (56*a^7 - 462*a^5 + 91*a^4 + 126*a^3 - 21*a^2 - a)
    of Multivariate Polynomial Ring in a, b over Rational Field

Eliminating a we obtain the ideal:
Ideal (56*b^7 - 462*b^5 + 91*b^4 + 126*b^3 - 21*b^2 - b)
    of Multivariate Polynomial Ring in a, b over Rational Field
```

Results were manually rearranged. We have a more or less direct access to the solutions of $(*)$ by asking for `J.variety()`, however, we also need to have the roots of the above generator of `Ja` in the ground field.
(Above, it was $\Bbb Q$, we must extend.)
We extend, so that the base field becomes $\bar{\Bbb Q}=$`QQbar`, since it "knows the roots". Then we ask for the values of $E$ in the critical points. These values are algebraic known numbers, there is no numerical step involved, to have them "exactly", we also ask for the minimal polynomial.

```
V = J.variety(ring=QQbar)
print('E-values in rational points of the variety defined by J / QQbar:')
for dic in V:
    a0, b0 = dic[a], dic[b]
    print(f'E( {a0}, {b0} ) = {E(a0, b0)} with minpoly = {E(a0, b0).minpoly()}')
```

Results:

```
E-values in rational points of the variety defined by J / QQbar:
E( 0, 0 ) = 3 with minpoly = x - 3
E( 0.2064248138599934?, -2.920240652156161? ) = 32.12852451463069? with minpoly = x^2 - 567/16*x + 1701/16
E( 0.549771246579960?, -0.5109092345889097? ) = 3.308975485369315? with minpoly = x^2 - 567/16*x + 1701/16
E( -0.5109092345889097?, -0.03886201199105012? ) = 3.308975485369315? with minpoly = x^2 - 567/16*x + 1701/16
E( 2.713815838296168?, 0.2064248138599934? ) = 32.12852451463069? with minpoly = x^2 - 567/16*x + 1701/16
E( -0.03886201199105012?, 0.549771246579960? ) = 3.308975485369315? with minpoly = x^2 - 567/16*x + 1701/16
E( -2.920240652156161?, 2.713815838296168? ) = 32.12852451463069? with minpoly = x^2 - 567/16*x + 1701/16
```

So the maximal value $\max E$ of $E$ on $\Bbb R^2$ is the root of the polynomial $16x^2 - 567x + 1701$ near $32$, which is:
$$
\color{blue}{
\max E=\frac 1{32}(567+45\sqrt{105})=\frac 9{32}(63+5\sqrt{105})\ .
}
$$
This is already a computer aided proof.

$\square$

(Sage makes exact computations inside `QQbar`.) We have the maximum. The OP also asks for the point(s) $(x,y,z)$ realizing this maximal value.

---

We note that for an optimal point $(a_0, b_0)$, the point $(b_0,c_0)$ with $c_0=-(a_0+b_0)$ is also optimal. This is so, since if $(x_0,y_0,z_0)=(1+a_0, 1+b_0, 1-a_0-b_0)$ is optimal for $x^3x+y^3z+z^3x$, if( and only i)f
$(y_0,z_0,x_0)=(1+b_0, 1+c_0, 1-b_0-c_0)$ is optimal.

This explains the structure of the extremal points:

```
V = J.variety(ring=QQbar)
print('Optimal E-values in rational points of the variety defined by J / QQbar:')
for dic in V:
    a0, b0, c0 = dic[a], dic[b], -(dic[a] + dic[b])
    if E(a0, b0) > 32:
        print(f'a0 = {a0} : b0 = {b0} : c0 = -(a0 + b0) = {c0}')
```

... which gives:

```
Optimal E-values in rational points of the variety defined by J / QQbar:
a0 = 0.2064248138599934? : b0 = -2.920240652156161? : c0 = -(a0 + b0) = 2.713815838296168?
a0 = 2.713815838296168? : b0 = 0.2064248138599934? : c0 = -(a0 + b0) = -2.920240652156161?
a0 = -2.920240652156161? : b0 = 2.713815838296168? : c0 = -(a0 + b0) = 0.2064248138599934?
```

Which is the equation satisfied by these points. We compute starting from the values `a0, b0, c0` from the last loop:

```
sage: a0, b0, c0
(0.2064248138599934?, -2.920240652156161?, 2.713815838296168?)
sage: a0 + b0 + c0
0
sage: a0*b0 + b0*c0 + c0*a0
-7.96760653723485?
sage: (a0*b0 + b0*c0 + c0*a0).minpoly()
x^2 + 33/4*x + 9/4
sage: a0*b0*c0
-1.635915686550325?
sage: (a0*b0*c0).minpoly()
x^2 + 13/8*x - 1/56
```

The two numbers above are $p = a_0b_0+b_0c_0+c_0a_0=-\frac 38(11+\sqrt{105})$, $q=-\frac 1{112}(91+9\sqrt{105})$. One can obtain this polynomial $x^3+px-q$ also as a factor of the generator of `Ja`, e.g.

```
K.<w> = QuadraticField(105)    # w is sqrt(105)
R.<a> = PolynomialRing(K)
factor(56*a^7 - 462*a^5 + 91*a^4 + 126*a^3 - 21*a^2 - a)
```

And we get:

```
(56) * a * (a^3 + (-3/8*w - 33/8)*a + 9/112*w + 13/16)
         * (a^3 + ( 3/8*w - 33/8)*a - 9/112*w + 13/16)
```

(manually adjusted).

---

Let us get the explicit formula for the roots of the equation $X^3+pX-q=0$. We try to write $p,q$ in the form $p=-3ST$, $-q=-S^3-T^3$, so that
$$
X^3+pX-q=
X^3 -3ST\; X - S^3-T^3
=(X-S-T)(\dots)\ ,
$$
and the roots are easily extracted now. From the above, we have the sum $q$ and the product $-(p/3)^3$ of $S^3$ and $T^3$, so these values are...
$$
\frac 12\left(-q\pm\sqrt{q^2+\frac 4{27}p^3}\right)
\ .
$$

This leads to the explicit (almost) radical formula for the roots:
$$
\color{blue}{a_0,b_0,c_0=
-2\Re\left(\ 
\frac 1{224}
\left(
91 + 9\sqrt{105} + 3i\sqrt{42(1199 + 117\sqrt{105})}
\right)
\ \right)^{1/3}
\ .}
$$
Here, there are three algebraic roots to be built over $\Bbb C$.
Let us check numerically the formula:

```
w = sqrt(105)
A0 = -(                2 * ( 1/224 * (91 + 9*w + 3*i*sqrt(42*(1199 + 117*w))) )^(1/3) ).real()
B0 = -( (-1 + i*sqrt(3)) * ( 1/224 * (91 + 9*w + 3*i*sqrt(42*(1199 + 117*w))) )^(1/3) ).real() 
C0 = -( (-1 - i*sqrt(3)) * ( 1/224 * (91 + 9*w + 3*i*sqrt(42*(1199 + 117*w))) )^(1/3) ).real()

print(f'A0 = {A0.n()}')
print(f'B0 = {B0.n()}')
print(f'C0 = {C0.n()}')
```

And we get (up to reordering) a numerical match with the already computed exact algebraic numbers `a0`, `b0`, `c0`:

```
A0 = -2.92024065215616
B0 = 2.71381583829617
C0 = 0.206424813859994
```

One has to add $1$ to get the corresponding values for $x,y,z$.

---

Note: One can use Lagrange multiplicators to solve the problem directly using $x,y,z$ (and the multiplier parameter $t$). Computer solution for this approach:

```
R.<x,y,z,t> = PolynomialRing(QQ)
f = x^3*y + y^3*z + z^3*x
h = (x + y + z - 3)
F = f + t*h
J = R.ideal([diff(F, v) for v in (x, y, z, t)])
V = J.variety(ring=QQbar)

for point in V:
    x0, y0, z0 = point[x], point[y], point[z]
    value = x0^3*y0 + y0^3*z0 + z0^3*x0
    if value > 20:
        print( f'x0 = {x0}')
        print( f'y0 = {y0}')
        print( f'z0 = {z0}')
        print( f'value = {value}\n')
```

And we get:

```
x0 = 3.713815838296168?
y0 = 1.206424813859994?
z0 = -1.920240652156161?
value = 32.12852451463069?

x0 = -1.920240652156161?
y0 = 3.713815838296168?
z0 = 1.206424813859994?
value = 32.12852451463069?

x0 = 1.206424813859994?
y0 = -1.920240652156161?
z0 = 3.713815838296168?
value = 32.12852451463069?
```

This would be a second (computer assisted) solution.

$\square$

---

Note that (cyclic and) only cyclic permutations of a solution is again a solution. So restricting to either $x<y<z$ or $y <x<z$ is *a priori* not allowed, both cases have to be considered.

Comment: Thanks for a nice computer solution, specially the use of sage.

Answer (score 0):

*A SOS (Sum of Squares) solution with computer*:

Denote $K = \frac{9(63+5\sqrt{105})}{32}$.

We have
$$
 K\left(\frac{x + y + z}{3}\right)^4 - (x^3y + y^3z + z^3x)
 = \alpha_1 f_1^2  
 + \alpha_2 f_2^2
 + \alpha_3 f_3^2
$$
where
\begin{align*}
 \alpha_1 &= \frac{567 - 16K}{13778100} > 0, \\[5pt]
 \alpha_2 &= \frac{472K - 5607}{292287082500} > 0,\\[5pt]
 \alpha_3 &= \frac{998K - 29538}{1491260625} > 0, \\[8pt]
 f_1 &= \left( 10\,{x}^{2}+20\,xy+20\,xz-14\,{y}^{2}+44\,yz-14\,{z}^{2}
 \right) K \\
 &\qquad -405\,xy+459\,{y}^{2}-999\,yz+459\,{z}^{2},\\[8pt]
 f_2 &= \left( 944\,xy-112\,xz-592\,{y}^{2}+1440\,yz-480\,{z}^{2} \right) K \\ 
 &\qquad -
 22239\,xy+8442\,xz+21987\,{y}^{2}-40635\,yz+17325\,{z}^{2},\\[8pt]
 f_3 &= \left( 16\,{y}^{2}-48\,yz \right) K+45\,xz-261\,{y}^{2}+918\,yz-405\,
 {z}^{2}.
\end{align*}